# How to add a subdomain in an asp.net core web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

So I have an asp.net web application (c#) and I wanna add a sub-site/sub-domain
like this:
`subsite.site.com`
Does anyone know how to?
Or do i have to do it anywhere else (not visual studio)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: During development not rightaway, unless you use IIS instead of IIS Express. During production you can use the `HostAttribute`